# Run same function parallelly with different items in the list in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the below code and I want to get the sum of each list in the nested listed parallelly using multi-processing or threading or any other  method in Python 3.x. How do I approach this? All the sub lists or atleast 2 sub lists should run the `addition` function at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

```
nested_list = [[2,3,4], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]

def addition(list):
  tot = sum(list)
  return tot

for list in nested_list:
  tot = addition(list)
  print (tot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need threads, because your task is CPU bound.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
 
with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(addition, nested_list))
```

**Other way**

```
import concurrent

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
     print(executor.map(addition, nested_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Give a woman or a man a fish and you feed her or him for a day. Teach woman or man to fish and you feed her or him for a lifetime.*

Check this [article](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#multiprocessing-version). It's awesome!
The case is not of a complicated matter, so you'll be ready to solve this and similar problems after 10-15 minutes of reading and trying.

Note! You wouldn't want to look toward `multithreading` in a case of [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) task (such as yours). In this case, in case of Python, only multiprocessing will introduce parallelism.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module can be used for process based parallel programming.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

nested_list = [[2,3,4], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(sum, nested_list))
```